# ID в массив

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! У меня проблема в присвоении ID'а в переменную. 
Пробовал делать

```
do { $.myrow['id'] = $_POST['.myrow['id'].']; }
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Не помогает ( пишет то что точка лишняя, а потом то что ] лишняя . . .

Comment: Вопрос абсолютно непонятен.  Что-то типа "как мне сделать то - сам не знаю что".
Напиши более подробно, что делаешь и что должно получиться в результате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, наверное, задумывалось:

```
do {
    $myrow['id'] = $_POST[ $myrow['id']];
} while (
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array( $result)
);
```

Точка в PHP — оператор конкатенации, «сшивает» две строки в одну: `'abc' . 'def' == 'abcdef'`.

Comment: Пропустил $ - изменил код в ответе.

Comment: Тут не принято выполнять работу за других и редко кто общается на «Ты».

Вывести что-то — например, [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: Имя переменной не должно начинаться с цифры.

Comment: print_r(<имя нужной переменной>)